# How to make a Facebook app inviting all user's friends to the app

Tags: facebook

I'd like to make a Facebook app which will Auto Tag all the user's friends and invite them to try the app.

Is there any way to do this ?

Sorry if i asked any kind of wrong questions, i am pretty new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to say no. This would basically amount to spam and everyone would be doing it. The new SDK also only lets you see a users friends that are already users of an app and unless it's a game you can't see who they can still invite.

Your best bet would be to use one of the facebook friend dialogs and ask prompt them to invite friends, but you cannot force them too. That would be a quick fire way to get your app removed

You can read more about what you can and can't do here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: I dont want the app to force them to invite mate, the app should ask an comfirmation from the user before inviting the friends from his account.

Comment: This is no longer possible

Comment: How is Meow Chat doing this?